# Adding array of objects to javascript from PHP

Tags: 7, javascript

This is a part of my script in template file where php code is used to generate js field of objects:

```
<?php $count = count($events); $counter = 1; ?>

<script>
  var events = [

  <?php foreach($events as $event) { ?>

    {
      date: '<?php echo $event['date']; ?>',
      linkTarget: "_blank",
      content: "<?php echo $event['content']; ?>",
      class: "<?php echo $event['class']; ?>"
    }
    <?php if($counter!=$count) { echo ','; $counter++; } ?>
  <?php } ?>

  ];
<script>
```

I know that we can add js variable by `drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('key' => 'value')), 'setting');` but how can we create the same js array as in example above in order not to use php code in js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an array to JS like this:

`drupal_add_js(array('my_module' => array('events' => $events)), 'setting');`

In javascript you can get the values like this:

```
Drupal.settings.my_module.events;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your custom module:

```
// build your associative array into $events variable
$events = json_encode(join(',', $events);
drupal_add_js(array('custom_module' => array('events' => $events)), 'setting')
```

And then in your template:

```
<?php print $events; ?>
```

Comment: This does not work. `$events = json_encode(join(',', $events);` returns string `"Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array"`. Btw. I need to use `Drupal.settings.my_module.events;` instead of `<?php print $events; ?>`